# Django Wagtail forms based on models

Tags: django, django-forms, wagtail

I have a simple model that references my Auth_User_model. I want to create a simple form that creates an OAuth2Client which inherits from functionality from OAuth2ClientMixin.

```
class OAuth2Client(models.Model, OAuth2ClientMixin):
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class FormPage(AbstractForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OAuth2Client
```

What I am unclear about is how to bind my Form Page to my model? I'm using this high level [tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#form-builder-render-email) but seems a bit geared to the AbstractEmailForm. Which doesn't work for me. How do I create a form based on a model?

Answer (score 1):

The `wagtail.contrib.forms` app is geared towards simple data collection such as surveys, where the form fields are defined editorially through the admin interface - this isn't the case here, where the form fields are inherently tied to the model definition set up in code. A Django [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/) is a better fit:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class OAuth2ClientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OAuth2Client
```

If you want to incorporate this form into a Wagtail page rather than a plain Django view, you can [override the `serve` method](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) on the page model, which has very similar behaviour to a Django view function (taking a request object as an argument, and returning a response object) - this is where you would put the logic for [checking `request.POST` and processing or rendering the form accordingly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#the-view).

Comment: Thank you very much in explaining the difference with the use cases of forms. 

However even looking through overriding the serve it's not clear how all this comes together please explain.